# SharePoint 2013 Custom login page?

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, visual-studio-2012, claims-based-identity, sts-securitytokenservice

I am using claim based authentication and I want to use a custom login page rather than the `_login/default.aspx` page. I have created an application page using Visual Studio 2012 and have deployed a login page in `_layouts` folder.
 What I understand is that I can't give that page as the custom login page because when I try to do that It gives me access error. Please guide me.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Who gives you access error and when?

Answer (score 0):

You can try following the advise from this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2010/07/09/creating-a-custom-login-page-for-sharepoint-2010.aspx). It also shows a guide on how to do it for claims based authentication. Please take note that creating custom login pages for SharePoint 2013 still uses the same concept from SharePoint 2010.